# JSON Deserializer returning NULL Values

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to consume a REST API via a C# Console Application and I've got as far as getting the webservice to return the JSON file, with the format:

```
{"status":200,"result":{"postcode":"SW1W0DT","quality":1,"eastings":528813,"northings":178953,"country":"England","nhs_ha":"London","longitude":-0.145828,"latitude":51.494853,"european_electoral_region":"London","primary_care_trust":"Westminster","region":"London","lsoa":"Westminster 023E","msoa":"Westminster 023","incode":"0DT","outcode":"SW1W","parliamentary_constituency":"Cities of London and Westminster","admin_district":"Westminster","parish":"Westminster, unparished area","admin_county":null,"admin_ward":"Warwick","ccg":"NHS Central London (Westminster)","nuts":"Westminster","codes":{"admin_district":"E09000033","admin_county":"E99999999","admin_ward":"E05000647","parish":"E43000236","parliamentary_constituency":"E14000639","ccg":"E38000031","nuts":"UKI32"}}}
```

I have created a class `AddressInfo` which is as follows:

```
public class AddressInfo {
    public string postcode { get; set; }
    public int quality { get; set; }
    public int eastings { get; set; }
    public int northings { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string nhs_ha { get; set; }
    public string admin_county { get; set; }
    public string admin_district { get; set; }
    public string admin_ward { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public string parliamentary_constituency { get; set; }
    public string european_electoral_region { get; set; }
    public string primary_care_trust { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
    public string parish { get; set; }
    public string lsoa { get; set; }
    public string msoa { get; set; }
    public string ccg { get; set; }
    public string nuts { get; set; }
    public object codes { get; set; } 
}
```

The code to call the API and get the values is:

```
string strJSON = string.Empty;

strJSON = rClient.makeRequest();
Console.Write(strJSON);

AddressInfo AI = new AddressInfo();
AI = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddressInfo>(strJSON);
```

However, when I debug, AI is returning the values as "NULL".

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that your JSON has a nested structure. The AddressInfo is contained within its `result` property, it isn't at the top level.

Your actual class structure to deserialize the entire JSON response should look something like this (I've called the class `JsonResponse` but you can name it whatever you want):

```
class JsonResponse{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public AddressInfo result { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize it like this:

```
JsonResponse res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponse>(strJSON);
AddressInfo addressInfo = res.result;
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it :P But yes, i'd suggest this too

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the fact that you need an outer class that has the properties `int status` and `AdressInfo result`.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is nested. The result is a nested object. That's why you are experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a separate class to deserialize the entire response, this can be done dynamically to achieve desired result:

```
var source = "(your JSON");
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(source);   
var d = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.result);
AddressInfo account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddressInfo>(d);
```